# iText flatten full PDF while creating

Tags: java, itext

How can I flatten a pdf with iText. The pdf is not a form field.

I want to flatten because if I don't flatten it while creating then printing process takes an extra steps of flattening the whole pdf and it consumes time.

Comment: You create your PDF from scratch. You don't add any form fields. In that case, you have a regular PDF without any interactivity. Why do you think you still have to flatten that PDF? Which "extra steps" are you referring to? There are no form fields; what else is there to flatten?

Comment: Usually here *flattening* refers to removing annotations (foremost form fields) integrating and integrating their appearance streams into the page content stream. But maybe the OP thinks of something else, maybe rendering as a bitmap to not have to deal with transparency, multiple colour spaces, etc.?

Comment: I got it. As there is no form field i dont need to flatten. Thanks....

Comment: When i print the document it flatten the document first then printing starts. i mentioned flattening before printing as "extra steps".